# How to Sort an Array on Update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoid, pymongo, mongodb-query

For example I a blog post in mongo:

```
{
  title: 'Some title',
  text: 'Text',
  tags: ['one', 'two', 'three']
}
```

Is there any elegant way to change `tags` ordering? (in any language or framework)

**upd:** in changing ordering I mean an ability to change the sequense of elements in some custom way - ex ['two', 'one', 'three']

There are obvious ways that I consider realy not perfect:

1. If I `copy and paste` (from server to client and back) tags every time the post is edited — someday race condition will happen.

   Example:

   If Ann started working on post (and loaded 3 tags to form), then Bob quickly ads one tag and saves the post, Ann will destroy his edit, because she has an old data.
2. I can check the length of list at the server side. But it seems weird and buggy to do it by hands — maybe someone's done it already?
3. I can put the nested list into special collection and use integer `order` — related db style.

So what is wrong?

- Maybe I missed some tool that already does the right thing with that ordering.
- Maybe I just don't get the idea of what actualy nested lists are for (maybe ordering is not their good side).

I would appreciate any help with this question.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by change tags ordering?

Comment: If I got your problem correctly, Maybe versioning is your solution: http://askasya.com/post/bestversion

Comment: @styvanesoukossi for example I got a todo list with tasks and want to sort the tasks in some custom way

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB has it's own methods to "sort" the values of an array, and you can do it without actually adding or removing any elements that are present in the array at the time of modification. This means that it is atomically performed on the server without needing to read the document over the wire and then send it back.

Considering your sample document you can so this:

```js
db.sample.update(
    {},
    { "$push": { "tags": { "$each": [], "$sort": 1 } } },
    { "multi": true}
)
```

Which would yield:

```js
{ 
    "title" : "Some title",
    "text" : "Text",
    "tags" : [ "one", "three", "two" ]
}
```

If you wanted to maintain the order more specifically you can always add an additional field as a sub-document to the array content:

```js
{ 
    "title" : "Some title",
    "text" : "Text",
    "tags" : [ 
        { "name": "one", "pos": 1 },
        { "name": "three", "pos": 3 },
        { "name": "two", "pos": 2 }
    ]
}
```

And then apply a similar **`$sort`** operation:

```js
db.sample.update(
    {}, 
    { "$push": { "tags": { "$each": [], "$sort": { "pos": 1 } } }},
    { "$multi": true }
)
```

With this result:

```js
{
    "title" : "Some title", 
    "text" : "Text", 
    "tags" : [ 
        { "name" : "one", "pos" : 1 },
        { "name" : "two", "pos" : 2 },
        { "name" : "three", "pos" : 3 }
    ] 
}
```

It's a little obscure at first, but along with the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) modifier the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) orders the content of the array when updated. So even when adding "nothing" to the array, as is represented by the empty array argument to **`$each`**, the sort is then applied to the whole content.

Of course, moving around array content in every update comes at a cost, and even while adding actual values this would work as well, it would have to be a separate operation when you "removed" items. There is no such present argument to a **`$pull`** operation.

You might want to consider just using the second form in your stored documents but do the actual "sorting" client side if this becomes an issue for application performance.